# I want to get_log from selenium webdriver on chrome *after* the page has finished loading

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using python selenium webdriver with it's `driver.get_log()` functionality to read console errors from browser.
It works ok, except for the fact that I'm interested in errors occuring after the page has completed its load (ad player which keeps loading content)

I tried running `execute_async_script()` in order to make the app wait 10 seconds while logging the errors, but it fails when the javascript ends due to "bad response from script".

Also tried `implicitly_wait()` `and set_script_timeout()` but no luck.
How can I accomplish this?

Thought about creating an infinite loop preventing the page to get to its finished loading event, but I'm not sure how to do that or whether it will cause another load of errors log which I'm not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can request for `document.readyState` as javascript which will return `complete` when page is loaded. Obviously it is blocking, and needs some kind of timeout.

```
def wait_for_page_to_load():
    state = ''
    counter = 0
    while state != 'complete':
        counter += 1
        if counter >60:
            return False
        state = _driver.execute_script('return document.readyState;')
        sleep(5)
    return True
```

Comment: Thank you, after trying our your idea I've figured out my mistake. It now works

Answer (score 0):

I made it, using `execute_async_script()` together with `set_script_timeout()`.
I set the async script to:

```
var start = new Date().getTime(); var end = start; while(end < start + 10000) { end = new Date().getTime(); }
```

And run it right after calling `driver.get(url)`
All I have to do now to play with the timout is to change `x` in `set_script_timeout(x)`